# Excel - Offset function with dynamic reference argument

Tags: excel, dynamic, offset

I'm having trouble making an offset function which allows the reference argument to be dynamic.

Effectively I want the offset function to always reference the last figure in a certain column, where the column of which is determined by a look up function from a name in another table. So if I input another new number below the last, the offset function's reference will automatically move to reference the new (last) data point.

I think the issue may be that I'm using a HLOOKUP to try and look up the new reference value.

i.e. =OFFSET((HLOOKUP(CELLX,CELLY,2, FALSE),0,0))

Is there any way to make the reference argument dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use INDIRECT? This will cause the OFFSET to reference a cell whose address is returned as a string by the HLOOKUP.

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(HLOOKUP(CELLX,CELLY,2,FALSE)),0,0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris Mack. It was an issue with referencing a text sting (which contained the cell reference) in the HLOOKUP. The INDIRECT func sorted it. i.e. '=OFFSET(INDIRECT(HLOOKUP(O14,$P$4:$R$7,4,FALSE),TRUE),0,0)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last number in a column with a Match function. If you want to offset DOWN **from** that last number, add a value to the row offset parameter. If you want to offset to another column, use the column offset parameter.

```
=OFFSET(A1,MATCH(99^99,A:A,1)-1,2)
```

In the screenshot the Offset returns a cell two columns to the right of the last number in column A.

[image]

Comment: not sure if Oliver's looking for a single value or a range. For the example you show with a single value LOOKUP can work more easily, e.g. `=LOOKUP(99^99,A:A,C:C)`

Comment: @barryhoudini Glad to see you back!

Comment: Thanks guys. I think the underlying issue was an error when referencing a text string in the HLOOKUP. Which was solved by an INDIRECT function. Apologies, I don't think I explained the issue 100% clear when asking the question. All solved now. All the best!